# How to get more the one values froma HashMap with getValue

Tags: java, hashmap, getvalue

I'm writing a program in JAVA and I'm using a HashMap.

```
 private HashMap<Integer,Plane> planes;
```

Plane is a class I have created:

```
public class Plane {
   private int planeNumber;
   private int departureTime;
   private int arrivalTime;
   private int flightDuration;
   private int aerialDrops;

   //constructors...
}
```

I then try to print all the components of the HashMap like that:

```
public void getAllAircrafts ()
{
    Set set = planes.entrySet();
    Iterator iterator = set.iterator();
    while(iterator.hasNext()) {
        Map.Entry mentry = (Map.Entry)iterator.next();
        System.out.print("Aircraft ID is: "+ mentry.getKey() + " ");
        System.out.println(mentry.getValue());
    }
}
```

The problem is I want to print the values of all the variables that describe plane, but instead I get aircrafts.Plane@15db9742 from mentry.getValue(). How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to override and add a *toString* method for **Plane** class,

```
    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Plane [planeNumber=" + planeNumber + 
                       ",departureTime=" + departureTime +  
                       ",arrivalTime=" + arrivalTime + 
                       ",flightDuration=" + flightDuration + 
                       ",aerialDrops=" + aerialDrops + "]";
    }
```

Right now you are using toString method of Object class parent

Answer (score 0):

A slight change would work fine as per you need :

```
   public class Plane {
   private int planeNumber;
   private int planeNumber;
   private int arrivalTime;
   private int flightDuration;
   private int aerialDrops;

   public String toString()
{
  return planeNumber +" "+planeNumber+" "+arrivalTime+" "+flightDuration+" "+aerialDrops
}
}
```